# How to automatically turn something off at 11pm and on at 6am?

Tags: electrical

I would like to find an electronic timer that can automatically turn my internet router off at exactly 11pm and on at 6am.

I would prefer a timer that is digital, so the time off and on is precise.

Where can I buy such a device?

Comment: This is a shopping question as written. Most routers can do the turning off internal to the router, and will thus stay synchronized to network time, while most timers will drift. So I'd suggest reading the manual/web page for the router. It will be far more precise and does not involve buying anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that your router can be plugged into an ordinary power strip. There are commonly available power strips with seven day digital timers built-in. The SE is not a product recommendation forum, which means it's not proper for me to provide specific product identifiers, but you can use your preferred search engine using the terms "digital timer power strip" and select the item which best meets your needs.

I have a pair of these devices in use, as the day of timed operation varies from week to week in my application. For your daily use, you may be able to locate a 24 hour version rather than a full-week version, making the programming slightly easier.